# How to take known relationship into consideration when looking for relationships within data?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm sure this problem could be presented in more abstract way, but let me paint the picture of what I've encountered when exploring data. Let's say I have a big proximity matrix of some books (A through ZZ). This matrix was created by examining people's libraries (sets of books each individual has). After visualizing this matrix, I'm noticing visible clusters of different genres of books - crime novels tend to have high proximity with one another, the same goes with romance, etc.

However, there are other peculiar patterns - groups of items with high proximity, with few parameters in common. Later I find out that these groups are items commonly sold together in bundle. Let's say that 10% of all users bought such bundles, and it's disrupting the genre clusters noticeably.

With this information, how can I tweak my visualization to 'disregard' these relationships? If I know exactly what items are sold together in such bundles (but not whether user having all books of a bundle means they bought that bundle), can I somehow tweak my proximity matrix to represent that?